# AES decryption after sending message to IP address

Tags: java, encryption, aes, datainputstream

So I am making an app that sends secure messages to the specified IP address. I am using AES to encrypt the message and that part works great. I am able to encrypt the message and also decrypt it before I send the message. However, when I try to decrypt a message that has been recieved from the server, I can not decrypt it. It gets displayed in it's encrypted form.

I get this error "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "ne"" and I think it may have to do with the character encoding or something? Is a string altered in any way when it is sent over a network?

Here are snippets that may be related to the issue.

```
public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
    return toHex(result);
}

public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
    byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
    return new String(result);
}


public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
    int len = hexString.length() / 2;
    byte[] result = new byte[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2),
                16).byteValue();
    return result;
}

public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
    if (buf == null)
        return "";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2 * buf.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        appendHex(result, buf[i]);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

This is where I do the decryption for the message to be displayed.

```
while (!goOut) {
    if (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {
        incoming = dataInputStream.readUTF();

        if(encrypt == true) {
            try{
                msgLog += AESHelper.decrypt(seed,incoming);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else msgLog += incoming;



        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                chatMsg.setText(msgLog);
            }
        });
```

This is encrypting the message:

```
OnClickListener buttonEncryptOnClickListener = new OnClickListener()   {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (chatClientThread == null) {
                return;
            }
            if (editTextSay.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                return;
            }

            if(!editTextSay.getText().toString().equals("")){

                String message = editTextSay.getText().toString();
                encrypt = true;
                int secLvl = Integer.parseInt(editTextSecurity.getText().toString());

                String encryptedMsg;
                try {
                     encryptedMsg = AESHelper.encrypt(seed, message);
                    textEncryptedmsg.setText(encryptedMsg);
                    textEncryptedmsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

        }
    };
```

This is sending the message:

```
OnClickListener buttonSendOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editTextSay.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                return;
            }

            if(chatClientThread==null){
                return;
            }

            if (encrypt == true){

                chatClientThread.sendMsg(textEncryptedmsg.getText().toString() + "\n");
            } else {
                chatClientThread.sendMsg(editTextSay.getText().toString() + "\n");
            }

            editTextSay.setText("");
            textEncryptedmsg.setText("");
            textDecryptedmsg.setText("");
            encrypt = false;
            incomingmsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    };
```

Comment: dataInputStream.readUTF - are you sending UTF?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what UTF is, but I thought that UTF was used to read in the input as a `String` which is what I need...? By the way, this is for an Android app. I don't know if thats important to know or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around the issue without using `CipherInputStream`. 
Whenever I encrypted a message and sent it, the encryption/decryption algorithm would not decrypt the message received from the server. Since the output encrypted message was identical to what I sent, I printed the incoming encrypted message into a `TextView` then I copied the `TextView` into a `String` and decrypted it and it works great now.

```
 while (!goOut) {


            if (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {

                final String incoming = dataInputStream.readUTF();



                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        incomingmsg.setText(incoming);
                        mustDecrypt = incomingmsg.getText().toString();



                        if (encrypt)
                            try {
                                mustDecrypt = AESHelper.decrypt(seed, mustDecrypt);
                                msgLog += mustDecrypt;

                            } catch (Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            else msgLog += mustDecrypt;




                        chatMsg.setText(msgLog);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you're sending the ciphertext in a hex encoded form. `DataInputStream#readUTF()` reads a [single Unicode character from the stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF%28%29). Since you're sending hex characters this will mean that a single ciphertext byte can be constructed from two of such Unicode characters.

The problem is that AES operates on blocks. Trying to decrypt every single "half"-byte separately won't work.

You will need to rewrite the decryption method to either

- use streaming decryption or
- read the whole ciphertext and decrypt in one go.

If you want to try streaming decryption, then you have basically two options:

- update the internal buffer of a Cipher object using the offset-version of [`Cipher#update()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#update%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29) or
- use a [`CipherInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html).

---

Here is an (pseudo-code) example of reading the whole thing before trying to decrypt it:

```
StringBuilder incoming = new StringBuilder();
while (!goOut && ) {
    incoming.append(dataInputStream.readUTF());
}
if(encrypt == true) {
    try{
        msgLog += AESHelper.decrypt(seed, incoming.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else msgLog += incoming;
```

Comment: I will try your suggestions and be back with an update shortly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not having any luck with getting the streaming decryption to work so I want to try decrypting the ciphertext in one go. I just want to make sure I understand something first though. Before I send the message, I am able to encrypt/decrypt it flawlessly. Is this because regular Strings are decrypted as one object? Howcome reading the input stream as a String and storing it then decrypting it doesn't give me the same result as decrypting the message before I send it? Why is the String recieved from `dataInputStream.readUTF()` decrypted at every "half-byte"?

Comment: You can see for yourself, it's not the complete ciphertext, but only one character. `dataInputStream.readUTF()` reads only one Unicode character. In hex every byte is encoded as two characters. I clarified this in my answer. Simply log the length of the `incoming` String.

Comment: I apologize about that. I should have read your answer throughly before asking you to restate what you said. Anyway, I have been mingling with decrypting the complete cipher in one shot. I've been thinking though, is there a way to get the input from `dataInputStream.readUTF()` and store it in blocks that AES would be familiar with decrypting?

Comment: Yes, that would be 16 byte blocks, but you almost certainly don't want to get closer to the AES primitive. You will need to handle the mode of operation and padding correctly. It's obvious that you haven't worked with streams in Java (that often). Maybe you should first collect the ciphertext on the client side and only then try to decrypt it. I've added an example.

Comment: I implemented that in my code but it gives me the same error. I honestly am trying to keep it as simple as possible because I am not expert in streams nor cryptography. I am trying to learn but don't want to make things too complicated for myself. I think I have no choice but to try to decrypt the stream cipher. I'm going to need some help though...

Comment: Maybe you can investigate further. What is the value of `incoming` when just before encryption and what is exactly the value that you send? Also, how do you send it (you haven't shared that code)?

Comment: I have added some more code to my question.  About the value of incoming, if I print it to screen it seems 100% identical to what I sent, but the decryption isn't working. I read that using `dataInputStream.readUTF()` writes the bytes to a modified version of UTF-8 encoding. I believe that "modificatio" is what is preventing the decryption from working. Oracle says it returns a "Unicode String". Do you know if thats any different from Java's standard Strings? [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUTF%28%29)[link]

Comment: Again, under the assumption that you're sending hex, that should be a problem. I should have asked about this sooner ... You've shown the exception message, but can you show the exception stacktrace? I have no idea where that exception originates.

Comment: When you say "sending hex", do you mean only 1-9 & a-f characters? If so, then no, I am not sending hex. I am sending regular String messages with all kinds of characters. And are you referring to the trace.txt that was created on my phone? Or is the exception stacktrace something else..?

Comment: 1. I mean the "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "ne"" and its stacktrace. Have you more exceptions? 2. Judging from code `AESHelper.encrypt(seed, message);` creates a hex encoded ciphertext string and my assumption is that you send exactly this string. How come you have different characters? 3. Have you checked that you have the exact same key on both sides?

Comment: So I tried getting the stacktrace but I got this when I entered the command:

FAILED
* Where:
Build file '/home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/AndroidChatClient/build.gradle' line: 5

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'AndroidChatClient'.
> Could not find method jcenter() for arguments [] on repository container.

As for the hex chars, yes, `encrypt` takes  string inputs for the key and the messsage, converts them to byte[], encrypts the message, then returns the key and message in byte[] form then converts them to hex and I send it.